# How to optimise unordered_map lookup?

Tags: c++, unordered-map

It seems that my program performance is bottlenecked by the following function:

```
inline bool isKeyInMap(const std::string key, std::unordered_map<std::string, MyClass>map)
{
    auto t = map.find(key);
    if (t == map.end()) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Is there a way to speed this up  ?

EDIT: The code was part of a larger function. The passing by value was not on purpose - I wrote the above one to remove any code which had nothing to do with the bottle neck. I was trying to see if there is a faster way  to do the following:

```
auto t = map.find(key);
if (t == map.end()) return false;
return true;
```

If I was as good a C++ programmer as the rest of you, I wouldn't be posting here in the first place. XD

Comment: Nothing to do with the question, but seriously... what's wrong with `return t != map.end();`?

Comment: @JamesKanze: That would be perfectly fine. But maybe the OP had actually a few lines of code before the `return true`, using `*t`. They removed them to see if the bottleneck disappeared, but it's sill there. Just guessing...

Comment: @rodrigo: If a function called `isKeyInMap` does "several other things", then you seriously need to have your structured programming sense checked. I recommend a healthy dose of Wirth until symptoms subside.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Hey, it can log the found item and the time it took to look it up... who knows?

Comment: @rodrigo: To log the time, use an SBRM timer.

Comment: @rodrigo Even then, you'd write an `if ( t != map.end() )`, and put the code in it.

Comment: One big reasons other languages may cache hashes is they pool immutable strings; they're taking the hit to hash into the pool for every string value created - seeking an existing matching string - so sure they want to save the hash and reference the string+hash thereafter.  In C++ we're not obliged to use a pool, but if we wanted to we could easily create a `pair<int32_t, std::string>` for hash & string values, then specify a hash function that returned `.first`.

Comment: Why has everyone carried on implementing their own versions of this, overlooking that `map.count(key)` already exists and does exactly this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main things related to performance here.

1) You are asking to optimize search operation in unordered_map.

Unordered map is implemented as some sort of hash table. So, look-up in it is O(1) most of the times. That's the minimum cost so there's no further optimization possible in that.

2) You are passing map by value which results in copying of all map elements to some other value.

**Only optimization you can do over here is pass map by const reference so as to avoid copying as well as changing contents of map.**

Comment: I'm not using boost. I'm using just regular c++.

Comment: @John my mistake but std::unordered_map is also hash map type.Yo can go through http://kariddi.blogspot.in/2012/07/c11-unorderedmap-vs-map.html

Answer (score 7):

Pass the arguments by reference, not by value:

```
bool isKeyInMap(const std::string & key,
                const std::unordered_map<std::string, MyClass> & m)
{
    return m.find(key) != m.end();
}
```

Otherwise you end up *copying everything* every time you're making a query.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing both the key and the map by value, and both of those copies are pretty expensive. Just changing the signature to:

```
inline bool isKeyInMap(const std::string& key, 
    const std::unordered_map<std::String, MyClass>& map);
```

should be dramatically faster.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you `pass by value`, you end up copying everything into temporary variables.
`Pass by reference` must do the trick:

```
inline bool isKeyInMap(const std::string& key, std::unordered_map<std::string, MyClass>& map) const
{
    auto t = map.find(key);
    if (t == map.end()) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Also, notice the `const` at the end of the method! Since you won't modify any member variable in this method, it's good to declare it `const`.

Comment: sure `isKeyInMap` is a member function and should be const ?

Comment: Since the question is tagged `c++`, I assume `class` is being used; and the method name and implementation suggests that it can be declared `const`

Comment: `inline` does not imply a member function

Comment: ...and C++ does not imply `class`, since it's a multi-paradigm language, not an enforced-OOP one, and so many things can - and in some cases should - be implemented as free functions (a common metric is if they only use other classes' public API, i.e. they don't exist to encapsulate anything). Besides - even if this *were* secretly a member function, it clearly doesn't use any member variables, so in that case it should've been `static`, which precludes the `const` (and is still subject to the point before about whether it *should* be any member).